# git - como puedo hacer merge/squash o rebase/squash con el minimo esfuerzo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Si tengo un feature branch `X` que arrancamos desde `main` y quiero convertir todos mis cambios en un solo cambio y colocarlo sobre la punta de `main`, como puedo hacer esto con el mínimo esfuerzo?

Considerar incluso que puede haber merges de `main` en en el feature branch que produjeron conflictos y que queremos evitar tener que hacerlos de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sería hacer el rebase a mano de forma interactiva

```
git rebase -i master
```

te saldrán todos tus commits con `pick`. cambia todos los `pick` por `squash` menos uno de ellos

```
pick afe3b6f Add errors to the schema
squash 3bb2680 something
```

Luego te pedirá cual quieres que sea el mensaje del commit y los juntará todos en uno.

Recuerda que al subir la rama deberás hacer un `git push origin HEAD --force` si ya la habías subido antes, ya que estas reescribiendo la historia.

Por último. Si mientras desarrollas ya tienes esto en mente...
Puedes hacer el primer commit con el mensaje final

los siguientes commits usa:

```
git commit --fixup <sha-primer-commit>
```

Y cuando quieras hacer el rebase:

git rebase -i --autosquash master

Y listo. Si usas github creo que no hace falta hacer el rebase y hay un botón al hacer el merge de una PR que lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: Esta forma (que es buena, no digo lo contrario), no te garantiza _mínimo esfuerzo_... _particularmente_ si hay merges con tu rama base donde has tenido que resolver conflictos.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la forma que requiere el mínimo esfuerzo, hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento:

```
git checkout X
git merge main
# Si hay conflictos, resolverlos y terminar el merge y continuar con la receta

git reset --soft main
git commit -m "Mi feature en un solo commit"
```